# Flutter - ListView not updating when new value added to firebase

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am pulling the listview from another dart file

Other data on the main page is populated by a stream builder

Container(  child: SingleChildScrollView(
child: SizedBox(
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .70,
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .95,
child: Expanded(child:
TodotaskSelected(tododocrefid)),
),
),
),

In TodotaskSelected the Listview is populated by a stream builder
the Listview contains cards that have a TextFormField.
I have tried adding visibility around the text form field and having a TextFormField without a initial value populate if it was new, but this did not work either.
I also added
setState(() {});
after the adding data to firestore in the button that is adding the data, but this did not help

The stream builder works when you view the page after leaving, but when you are on the main page and add a new item, the item is added but it populated with the previous items value from the TextFormField

I have tried adding visibility around the text form field and having a TextFormField without a initial value populate if it was new, but this did not work either.
I also added
setState(() {});
after the adding data to firestore in the button that is adding the data, but this did not help

I am expecting to have a new blank card appear when I add a new blank card. I do not want to the value of the previous TextFormField input value to populate on new cards.

TodotaskSelected Code:

```
 import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
 
 class TodotaskSelected extends StatefulWidget {
  final String tododocrefid;
 
 const TodotaskSelected(this.tododocrefid, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);
 
   @override
   TodotaskSelectedState createState() => TodotaskSelectedState();
 }
 
 class TodotaskSelectedState extends State<TodotaskSelected> {
 
 late String tododocrefid = widget.tododocrefid;
    bool isChecked = false;
  
   
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
       floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.small(onPressed: (){  }),
       backgroundColor:
        Colors.white, body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
         stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                 .collection('todo')
                 .doc(tododocrefid)
                 .collection('task')
               .orderBy("dateadded", descending: true)
                 .snapshots(),
         builder: (context, snapshot)
          {
           if (!snapshot.hasData) {
             return  const Center(
               child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
             );}
  if (snapshot.data == null) {
    return const Center(
                 child: Text(
                   "Add Task",
                   style:  TextStyle(
                    // color: Colors.white70,
                   ),
                 ),
               ); 
            }
 if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){}  return ListView.builder(
               itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
               itemBuilder: (context, index) { Map data = snapshot.data!.docs[index].data() as Map;
                 DateTime mydateTime = data['dateadded'].toDate();
                 String formattedcommentdateadded =
                     DateFormat.yMMMd().add_jm().format(mydateTime);
                     bool checkvalue=  data['taskcheckbox'];
                  //late bool isChecked=  data['todocommentcheckbox'] ?? false;
                 return  InkWell(
                   onTap: () {  },child:
                 Card(
                  // color:Color.fromARGB(255, 166, 215, 255),
                     child: Padding(
                       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                       child: Row(   children:
                         [
                           Checkbox(
                           value: checkvalue,
                           onChanged: (bool? value) { // This is where we update the state when the checkbox is tapped
                               setState(() {
                                 isChecked = value!;
                                       FirebaseFirestore.instance
                              .collection('todo')
                              .doc(tododocrefid)
                              .collection('task')        
                              .doc("${data['taskdocid']}")
                               .update(
                                           {'todoactualcompleteddate': DateTime.now(),
                                           'taskcheckbox':value,} ); });}, ),
                           Column(children:[
                           Row(
                             crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                             children: [
                               SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *.3,),
                             Text(formattedcommentdateadded, style:TextStyle(
                               fontSize: 8,
                               color: Colors.grey[700]) ,)
                             ]),
                  Visibility(
                   visible: data['updated'],
                   replacement:  SizedBox(
                               width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *.67,
                               child:
                               TextFormField(
                         decoration: const InputDecoration.collapsed(
                           hintText: "Task",
                         ),
                         style: const TextStyle(
                           fontSize: 12.0,
                           //color: Colors.grey,
                         ),
                         initialValue:  "",
                         enabled: true,
                         onChanged: (val) {
                           FirebaseFirestore.instance
                         .collection('todo')
                           .doc(tododocrefid)
                           .collection('task')
                           .doc("${data['taskdocid']}")
                         .update({'task': val,
                         'updated':true
                         });
                                           },
                         maxLines: 2,
                         validator: (val) {
                           if (val!.isEmpty) {
                             return "Can't be empty !";
                           } else {
                             return null;
                           }
                         },
                       ),),
                   child:  SizedBox(
                               width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *.67,
                               child:
                               TextFormField(
                         decoration: const InputDecoration.collapsed(
                           hintText: "Task",
                         ),
                         style: const TextStyle(
                           fontSize: 12.0,
                           //color: Colors.grey,
                         ),
                         initialValue:  "${data['task']}",
                         enabled: true,
                         onChanged: (val) {
                           FirebaseFirestore.instance
                         .collection('todo')
                           .doc(tododocrefid)
                           .collection('task')
                           .doc("${data['taskdocid']}")
                         .update({'task': val, });  },
                         maxLines: 2,
                         validator: (val) {
                           if (val!.isEmpty) {
                             return "Can't be empty !";
                           } else {
                             return null; } },),)), ],),
                  IconButton(onPressed: (){delete(data);}, 
                  color: Colors.red[800],
                  icon:  const Icon(Icons.clear,)  )], ), ), ));});},));}
   
   delete(data){
 FirebaseFirestore.instance
                 .collection('todo')
                 .doc(tododocrefid)
                 .collection('task')
                 .doc(data['taskdocid'])
                 .delete();
                  setState(() {});}    }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please share your full code? It is difficult to provide an answer without seeing exactly what is happening in the code.

Comment: @most200 I added the code for the TodotaskSelected code that populates the container on the main page